# What are empty comments <!--!--> used for in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

In Blazor, I often come across empty comment tags, such as `<!--!-->`, in the generated HTML markup. These can be confusing when I'm inspecting the page's HTML source. I'm sure there's a valid reason for their presence, but I'm curious about what they are.

Comment: If you are using a Chromium browser you can tell the browser to hide them with the "Hide HTML Comments" command in the dev tools.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. In MS Edge setting is called "Show HTML comments" and by default it is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<!--!-->` are used by the internal JavaScript algorithm to determine the beginning and end of components. That way no additional artificial wrapper elements are needed. The usage of comments spares a lot of runtime checks when modifying the DOM.

---

**Example**: Suppose we have a component `<MyComponent/>`:

```
<h1>@Title</h1>
<p>@Description</p>
```

Now you render a bunch of them to your page and want to add another one later on:

```
<MyComponent/>
<MyComponent/>
 <MyComponent/> <-- Insert another one here
<MyComponent/>
```

How would you know what elements in the DOM belong to which component instance? The  comments help Blazor to keep track of that separation.

For people familiar with [React](https://react.dev/): I think the concept is very comparable to [Fragments (`<></>`)](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment) yet works quite differently under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

They are place-holders used by the Blazor Virtual Dom.
I suppose they are tagged&tracked somewhere.

So you will have to learn to live with them.